# having been vs being

Tags: tense

In the following sentence, I am supposed to pick correct choice:

> Several guests complained about **(being/having been/to have been)**
> served cold food last night.

I think it should be **having been** but the answer is given **being**. Can someone explain ?

What about this?:

> He complained **(of/about)(being/having been)** treated unfairly.

Please explain your choices.

Comment: _Having been_ would be perfectly acceptable. It's what I would use myself, since the reference is to something that had happened the previous day.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complained+about+being%2Ccomplained+about+having+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplained%20about%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomplained%20about%20having%20been%3B%2Cc0), the "perfect" form is far less common. Partly because there *can* be contexts where it simply isn't suitable (if they're complaining ***while it's still happening***). But mainly because ***on average*** we prefer to use simpler tense forms where there's no risk of being misunderstood.